# Printing 2d array in app gives blank screen

Tags: java, android

i made 2d array that contains names and task.
the function give random task to the users.
when i try to print the array that contain the users and the random tasks i get a blank screen.

```
public String[][] start() {
    int[] taken = new int[this.numberOfRowsT()];
    String[][] h = new String[numberOfRowsN()][(numberOfRowsT()) / (numberOfRowsN()) + 1];
    int a = 1;
    int x;


    for(int b = 0; b < this.numberOfRowsN(); b++){
        h[b][0] = this.getUsersByID(b+1).toString();
    }

    while (a != this.numberOfRowsT()) {
        x = (int) Math.random() * ((this.numberOfRowsT()) + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < taken.length; j++) {
            if (x == taken[j]) {
                j = -1;
                x = (int) Math.random() * ((this.numberOfRowsT()) + 1);
            }
        }
        taken[a] = x;                                   // acceptable num from here

        h[((a % this.numberOfRowsN()) + 1)][this.numberOfRowsN() % a] = this.getTaskByID(x).toString();
        a++;

    }
    return h;
}

     public void onClick(View v) {
            String[][] h = mydb.start();

            for (int i = 0; i < mydb.numberOfRowsN(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mydb.numberOfRowsT() / 
                                                mydb.numberOfRowsN(); j++)
                    if (h[i][j] != null)
                        l.append(h[i][j]);
                l.append("\n"); // Append newline after every row
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Where in this code is any printing taking place?

Comment: You're getting a blank screen because you're not doing any printing.

Comment: Unrelated: please use **meaningfull** names for your variables. v, h, l ... they all mean absolutely nothing to human readers. Use names that mean what they say, and say what they mean.

Comment: What is `l` in `onClick` and where is it declared?

Comment: l is the text view  where i want the data print.

Comment: the onclick in the java file of the xml

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
String[][] h = mydb.start();
```

I guess you want to use that 2D array to collect all the strings to print. 
Thing is: you only declare and **fill** that array.

But it is a local variable, and it goes out of scope as soon as `onClick()` has run.

Thus: if you want to *print* things, then you need to do something with the data you collected. Either put into some UI element, or at least log it, or send to `System.out.printn()` (that of course only works when you have a console, and isn't a viable thing for an Android app).